# problems scheduling tasks/ need alternatives

Tags: windows, windows-task-scheduler

I am trying to schedule a task that would run a simple batch file that runs some python script. The python script is a test that creates an empty text file. When I run the batch file the text file is created with no issues.

When I try to create a task with the scheduler and run it, nothing happens (whether I wait for the actual time or run manually). I changed the options to run with highers priviledge and denies access, even if I gave my account complete admin rights and added the user to the 'log on as a batch job' in local security policy.

Do you guys have any ideas as to why this is happening?

Are there any free applications that can do this same task?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a good alternative that works for me, its simple and free: https://www.splinterware.com/